# В vs code не могу настроить pylint для python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

Pylint установлен с помощью pip3, в vscode установлен python3 как интерпретатор. Постоянно показывает, что не установлен pylint, а при установке, что уже установлен.

Comment: убедитесь, что `pip3` выполняется с использованием именно того python3 исполняемого файла, который у вас в vs-code прописан (на Unix, команду выполните: `head -1 $(command -v pip3)` и сравните с `command -v python3` выводом в контексте vs code).